# Make XMLHttpRequest uploader work with multiple files

Tags: javascript, php, apache, file-upload, xampp

I sourced this code (was free to use) but I can't seem to make it upload multiple files, I did create my own index.html and allowed to select multiple files.

Every time I select multiple files, the uploader just uploads the first file I selected and ignores the others. I don't know what to modify in the .js since I never used JavaScript, might be something really obvious but since I just started learning programming on my own, i couldn't figure it out

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form"),
  fileInput = document.querySelector(".file-input"),
  progressArea = document.querySelector(".progress-area"),
  uploadedArea = document.querySelector(".uploaded-area");

// form click event
form.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fileInput.click();
});

fileInput.onchange = ({
  target
}) => {
  let file = target.files[0]; //getting file [0] this means if user has selected multiple files then get first one only
  if (file) {
    let fileName = file.name; //getting file name
    if (fileName.length >= 12) { //if file name length is greater than 12 then split it and add ...
      let splitName = fileName.split('.');
      fileName = splitName[0].substring(0, 13) + "... ." + splitName[1];
    }
    uploadFile(fileName); //calling uploadFile with passing file name as an argument
  }
}

// file upload function
function uploadFile(name) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //creating new xhr object (AJAX)
  xhr.open("POST", "php/upload.php"); //sending post request to the specified URL
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", ({
    loaded,
    total
  }) => { //file uploading progress event
    let fileLoaded = Math.floor((loaded / total) * 100); //getting percentage of loaded file size
    let fileTotal = Math.floor(total / 1000); //gettting total file size in KB from bytes
    let fileSize;
    // if file size is less than 1024 then add only KB else convert this KB into MB
    (fileTotal < 1024) ? fileSize = fileTotal + " KB": fileSize = (loaded / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2) + " MB";
    let progressHTML = `<li class="row">
                              <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
                              <div class="content">
                                <div class="details">
                                  <span class="name">${name} • Uploading</span>
                                  <span class="percent">${fileLoaded}%</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress-bar">
                                  <div class="progress" style="width: ${fileLoaded}%"></div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </li>`;
    // uploadedArea.innerHTML = ""; //uncomment this line if you don't want to show upload history
    uploadedArea.classList.add("onprogress");
    progressArea.innerHTML = progressHTML;
    if (loaded == total) {
      progressArea.innerHTML = "";
      let uploadedHTML = `<li class="row">
                                <div class="content upload">
                                  <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
                                  <div class="details">
                                    <span class="name">${name} • Uploaded</span>
                                    <span class="size">${fileSize}</span>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                              </li>`;
      uploadedArea.classList.remove("onprogress");
      // uploadedArea.innerHTML = uploadedHTML; //uncomment this line if you don't want to show upload history
      uploadedArea.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", uploadedHTML); //remove this line if you don't want to show upload history
    }
  });
  let data = new FormData(form); //FormData is an object to easily send form data
  xhr.send(data); //sending form data

}
```

Comment: JAVA is NOT JavaScript

Comment: If you do not know how the file input works and the files array is accessed, then it is hard to explain you in such a simple manner that you can fix the issue